# remove current breadcrumbs in sentry

Tags: python, sentry

I have simple synchronous code like this:

```
import sentry_sdk
from time import sleep


sentry_sdk.init(MY_DSN)
while True:
    # remove sentry breadcrumbs here, so they would not accumulate
    try:
        do_my_stuff()
    except:
        handle_my_exception()

    sleep(some_non_linear_algorithm())  # I would like not to use crontab
```

When exception occurs sentry captures it and all breadcrumbs from previous iterations, so I need to delete all current breadcrumbs in the beginning of each iteration. But I cannot find any API to do that in sentry documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code in this:

```
with sentry_sdk.push_scope():
    try:
        ...
    except:
        ...
```

This will make sure that you don't leak breadcrumbs, tags, etc between iterations.

Alternatively you can use:

```
with sentry_sdk.configure_scope() as scope:
    scope.clear()
```

Comment: This works, but instead of scope.clear() I use scope.clear_breadcrumbs() (I do not use any tags yet).